# Understanding the relationship between protocols and delegates

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm reading "Programming in Objective C" by Stephen G. Kochan, and in chapter 11 he mixed with a bit about: categories, protocols, delegation, informal protocols.

Now, he just talked a bit about everyone of them and it got me more confused...I know that delegation is one of the most important subjects in obj c and that it goes along with protocols.

Please help, it's important for me so I will not mess it up.
tnx

Comment: This question isn't really a good fit for SO and will probably be closed shortly.  However, I would suggest researching the areas that you aren't sure about in other sources, as they are vital to properly understanding existing classes and making the best classes that you can in your own code.

Comment: This is an offtopic, but the answer is "as early as possible": assuming that you would like to program an iOS or OS X with it, you want to learn about delegates right away, at least on a very superficial level. You can go deeper when you feel ready, but it's a good idea to start early.

Comment: Do you happen to know Java? A protocol in obj-c is sort of similar to an interface in Java. In both langauges there is no multiple inheritance. A protocol describes a set of mehtods which a class provides but which it did not inherit. So a second class can know whether a certain set of methods is availalbe or not. Delegation is simply using protocols for some sort of call-back functions. So if a controller creates a table the table wants to know from where to fetch the data. The controller then is or names a delegate which provides methods to feed the data into the table. That's it basically.

Comment: @HermannKlecker i know some c. But i pretty much get the concepts from what he explained, but since I know this concepts are much more full and important then couple of pages, so I though it's not enough.

Comment: I know it is confusing. But in the end it is not even complicated. It's just a way for two classes to formally communicate with each other.

Comment: @HermannKlecker so what you basically say, is to keep going with the book, and when I physically need to deal with delegation and protocols I just will?

Comment: @nir, sort of. Once you used it you will instantly realize its purpose. The syntax is much more confusing than the real thing behind it.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing "special" about delegates.  They're just classes/protocols like any other object.  It's just how they're used that's (a little) different, if you insist on looking at them differently.

Comment: @vikingosegundo why did you close it? isn't it could be helpful for someone that is trying to get their head around delegate concept? I think the answer bellow would help to a bunch of newbies, maybe the title of the question needs to be change

Comment: Take a look at the FAQ which is linked to in the message displayed when your question was closed. Basically, you asked a question which is subjective and doesn't have a "correct" answer, and is likely to create a debate or discussion.  The FAQ has specific details though about the right kinds of questions for SO.

Comment: @lnafziger Sure, thank you for the explanation. Although I still think if you would edit the title to something else it could help allot of newbies understanding the relationship between protocols and delegates.

Comment: Well,  it doesn't get deleted so it will still be here.  However,  if you do edit the title/question to something more appropriate,  then it will possibly be re-opened.  (Notice that you can always edit your own question by clicking edit at the bottom of your question. )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try and explain delegation for you. It's really simple when you do know, but it takes time to get your head around it!

Let's say you have two classes, a `Calculator` class that performs calculations and a `CalculatorScreen` class that is used to present the result of a calculation to a user. The Calculator class should tell the CalculatorScreen when it has finished performing a calculation so the latter can update the UI.

A **protocol** provides a way to define a set of methods that are somehow related with a specified name. You could have a number of methods *defined* in a protocol called CalculatorDelegate in the Calculator class, but the method *implementations* are defined elsewhere.

The class that defines the protocol (in this case Calculator) can tell a **delegate** (an object that **conforms** to the protocol - in this case CalculatorScreen) to implement the method. The calculator class might finish an addition calculation and tell its delegate (the screen) to update. You get me?

Sorry, as I was writing I realized it is hard to explain and sympathized with every author that has tried!

iOS Example:
When you set up a table on the iPad's display, you use the UITableView class. But that class doesn't know what the title of the table is, or how many sections and rows it is to have, or what to fill it with. So it delegates that responsibility to you by defining protocols called UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate. When the UITableView needs to know some information, for example, number of rows, it calls the appropriate method on the delegate (your own class), the delegate class contains the implementation of those methods defined in the protocol.

In answer to your question, I'd drop the book for a bit and start coding what you have learned so far in a dummy app! The best way to learn is to do (for me at least).

Comment: awesome answer Adam thanks! I am practicing actually, after each chapter there are around 10 exercises. But the only exercises in the end of this chapter where on Categories..@AdamWaite